# Error after fresh installation

Tags: wordpress, error, installation

CiviCRM first-time user here, trying to install on a system with the following specs:

- Host: Hostgator shared hosting
- CMS: WordPress 5.7.2
- Database client version: libmysql - 5.6.43
- PHP version: 7.3.28

I downloaded civicrm-5.39.0-wordpress.zip from the CiviCRM website and uploaded using the WordPress plugin-install.php tool. Success.

It loads right into the CiviCRM Installer. There was one warning which appeared to have an optional fix - it suggested something about switching over to utf8mb4. I ignored that because it said the installation should still work. I selected the base option I wanted - no sample data, membership module only.

After the installer ran, I was taken to a screen within WordPress that said there was a critical error and I should check the site admin email inbox. I'm not the site admin, so I checked the error log via File Manager and pulled this out:

```
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home3/jmaurer/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/SettingsBag.php on line 354
```

I refreshed the page with the "critical error" message and this is what was displayed:

```
Initialization Error

Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => simpleHandler
        )

    [code] => -18
    [message] => DB Error: no such table
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'jmaurer_mcoanew.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'jmaurer_mcoanew.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
 [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'jmaurer_mcoanew.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]"]
```

I deactivated the plug-in via File Manager so at least the site is back up and running, but I'm at a loss as to what's causing this installation issue. Help!?!?

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Bluehost Fresh install of WP v 5.7.2
PHP v 7.3.28
MYSQL 5.6.41-84.1 Crahses the same as yours with the same results I did notice in php.ini the max_ececution_time is 30 and should be 240
and max_input_time is 60 and should be 120
I don't kknow if this is the problem or not, but with over 13,000 files in civicrm it is hard to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for the response, in a way I'm happy to see someone else is having this issue lol. I have found some articles that talk about modifying different mySQL configuration options, but I'm on shared hosting so I don't have access to change those things. Are the max_execution_time and max_input_time mySQL config options, or are they something I can modify in WordPress?

**edit**

I found hostgator.com/help/article/php-settings-that-cannot-be-changed, which indicates that max_execution_time and max_input_time are unable to be changed on shared hosting plans. So, I hope that's not it.

Comment: They are in php.ini and at least on Bluehost you can configure them per site. I changed to the recommended settings and it crashed again just now. Fortunately this is a test site and crashing WP is not a total disaster. I really hope we can get this resolved, as it is a perfect app for our organization. There is something going on in the way it is trying to create tables, as there is one that is empty, but that is as far as it gets. It doesn't appear to be a db connection issue, as it does create one table.

Comment: This is not an Answer and will probably be deleted. perhaps you could repost as a comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11597)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been discussed at chat.civicrm.org so just updating this question with that conversation.

The MySQL requirements for CiviCRM are:

**MySQL 5.7.5+ or MariaDB 10.0.0.2+**

The full CiviCRM hosting requirements can be found [Here](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/)

Or you can have a conversation with one of the many partners to discuss hosting your CiviCRM. [Partners Hosting](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country_id=&custom_157=Hosting&custom_181=All&cms=All)

Comment: At this point, this should be the top answer. The recent switch to MySQL 5.7.5+ is important to note, as somehow I missed that in my initial investigation. We are now investigating hosting through a CiviCRM partner.

Answer (score 2):

I think an answer is needed here that says something like 'it is not recommended to try hosting with low spec shared hosting such as hostgator or bluehost'

Some documentation [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/planning/hosting/)

Comment: I think that is a fair assessment, although if any other devs are like me, we spend a lot of time working in hosting environments that we didn't set up. It certainly was a time-consuming process to identify all of CiviCRM's requirements and match against poorly-documented and confusing hosting specs. Not disagreeing with you, but that's the reality of the situation sometimes. I'm still not entirely sure why the installation failed but in hindsight it was going to be a stretch knowing that this was shared hosting through HostGator.

Comment: i guess for those types of situations having good documentation about what hosting requirements are likely to succeed could save folk time diving in to wrestling with sub-par hosting to get civi going

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Exchange and CiviCRM!

The fact that `civicrm_setting` is missing from your database suggests that something went wrong during installation and the data wasn't loaded into the database at all.  If you have access to view the database, check to see if any tables at all are installed.  You may also get real-time help at https://chat.civicrm.org if folks are around.

Comment: Via phpMyAdmin, I can see that only one table was added: civicrm_address_format. I have uninstalled and re-installed several times, and every time I get the same errors, and this is the only table added to the database during installation. I'll check out the chat and see if anyone is on - thank you for your response! I'm optimistic that we can get this working.